Are all non-zero Lipschitz functions bounded away from zero with high probability?
Let $X\sim \rho_X$ be a random variable taking value in $[0,1]^d$, with distribution $\rho_X $ assumed to be absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Now let $f : [0,1]^d \to [-1,1]$ be a Lipschitz-continuous (and piecewise linear, but I doubt that matters) function. I am wondering if the following is true (and if it's not, what more do we need to make it true) :

Claim : If $\mathbb P(|f(X)| = 0) = 0$, then there exist positive constants $C,q$ such that $\mathbb P(|f(X)|\le t) \le Ct^q$ for all $0<t\le 1$.

Intuitively, I expect this to be true because $C$ and $q$ can be arbitrarily large, so we can make the upper bound "blow up", and get it to be larger than $1$ for arbitrarily small $t$. So basically the question is can $\rho_X $ concentrate an arbitrarily large amount of mass in the sets $f^{-1}([-t,t])$ for small $t$ ? Furthermore, $f$ being Lipschitz, I expect that some things could be said about the size of $f^{-1}([-t,t])$ in terms of $\text{Lip}(f)$, but haven't found anything so far.

Attempt : Assume that the desired property does not hold, this means that for all $C,q$, there exists a $t\in(0,1]$ such that $\mathbb P(|f(X)|\le t) > Ct^q $. Now fix $C=C_0$ and $q=q_0$, by assumption there exists $t_0\le 1$ such that $\mathbb P(|f(X)|\le t_0) > C_0 t^{q_0}$. But now note that
$$1 = \mathbb P(|f(X)|\le 1) \ge \mathbb P(|f(X)|\le t_0) > C_0 t_0^{q_0} \implies t_0\le C_0^{-1/q_0} $$
From this observation, my goal was to construct sequences $(C_k), (q_k)$ such that $C_k^{-1/q_k} \to 0$ and $C_k (t_k)^{q_k}\to 1$ as $k\to\infty$. The problem is that, while it is easy enough to make $C_k^{-1/q_k} \to 0$, there is no control on $t_k$ so there is no way to ensure $C_k (t_k)^{q_k}\to 1$, regardless of the choice of $C_k$ and $q_k$. Is there a way to make this approach work ?

Letting $t \to 0$, I think a trivial necessary condition is that $\mathbb{P}( f(X) = 0 ) = 0$ rather than $<1$ ? Anyway, even taking $d=1$ and $f = \text{id}$ I think you can not get such a bound because $X$ is still a completely arbitrary random variable. You are essentially asking if an arbitrary absolutely continuous cdf is dominated by a function of the form $C t^q$ around $0$.

I can expand on these ideas in an answer if you wish, but I thought maybe you forgot some simple detail that would make the problem more reasonable, so I'm keeping this in the comments just yet.

@Adayah thanks for your comments. You're right about the $\mathbb{P}( f(X) = 0 ) = 0$, thing, I thought this was implied by absolute continuity of $\rho_X$ but I was wrong. I edited the question. Regarding your other point, the identity function is not admissible (you'd need to truncate it), but if you can show me how to extend this idea to construct a counterexample, I'll happily accept your answer !

In what sense is the identity function "not admissible"? Regarding the more general idea, do you know an example of a continuous increasing function on $[0,1]$ that takes value $0$ at $0$ but is not dominated by the function $Ct^q$ for any $C, q$? It's basically the same question as whether a function can go to $\infty$ as $t\to\infty$ but slower than any polynomial.

@NicholasBurbank Identity is not admissible because it's not $[-1,1]$ valued, but its truncation $x\mapsto (x\wedge 1)\vee -1$ is. Regarding your second point, how do you define "dominated" ? If it's in the usual asymptotic sense, then yes I know many such functions, e.g. $t\mapsto e^t -1$. But it doesn't matter because  you can always find $C$ and $q$ large enough to be above it on the interval $[0,1]$ (for instance $t\mapsto 2\sqrt t$)

Identity as a function $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is not $[-1, 1]$-valued? Sorry, I don't follow...

Oops, my bad, identity is valid of course. Sorry for the confusion !

TL;DR: Scroll to the end for just the counterexample.
How to approach the problem
Take $d = 1$ and $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ the identity function. In terms of the cumulative distribution function of $X$, i.e. $F_X(t) = \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant t)$, we can phrase the claim as follows:

If $F_X(0) = 0$, then there exist $C, q > 0$ such that $F_X(t) \leqslant Ct^q$ for $0 < t \leqslant 1$.

Note that if $F_X$ were allowed to be an arbitrary function $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$, the claim would be trivially false.
But what restrictions are imposed on $F_X$ as a cdf of $X$?

Fact. A function $F : \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ is a cdf of some (real-valued) random variable $X$ if and only if:

$F$ is non-decreasing,
$\lim_{t \to -\infty} F(t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = 1$,
$F$ is right-continuous, i.e. $F(t) = \lim_{s \to t^+} F(s)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.


Additionally, if $F$ is already the cdf of a random variable $X$:


$X$ has values in $[0, 1]$ (almost surely) iff $F(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$ and $F(1) = 1$,
$X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure iff $F$ is an absolutely continuous function.


Note that these conditions put no restrictions on the rate of growth of $F$ around $0^+$. In particular, a standard example of a function not dominated by anything of the form $C t^q$:
$$F_0(t) = \frac{1}{\ln \frac{1}{t}} \text{ for } t \in (0, 1)$$
already almost satisfies these conditions: it is increasing, absolutely continuous and approaches $0$ as $t \to 0^+$. We just need to adjust it to meet them all:
The counterexample
$$F(t) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{for } t \leqslant 0, \\
\frac{1}{\ln \frac{1}{t}} & \text{for } 0 < t \leqslant \frac{1}{e}, \\
1 & \text{for } \frac{1}{e} < t.
\end{cases}$$
It follows that $F$ is a cdf of some absolutely continous random variable $X$ with values in $[0, 1]$, which we can take as a counterexample to the claim.


Nice (and unexpected) ! I didn't know about this function $F_0$, thank you for even taking the time to provide a plot.

I'm glad I could help! Since it appears to me that you missed Nicholas Burbank's point in the comments - $e^t-1$ is not exactly the example you should consider - allow me to expand on this as well. In view of the substitution $x = \frac{1}{t}$, finding a function that is eventually bigger than everything of the form $Ct^q$ as $t \to 0^+$ is the same as finding a function that is eventually bigger than everything of the form $C x^{-q}$ as $x \to \infty$. Since $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ satisfies the latter, $\frac{1}{\ln \frac{1}{t}}$ satisfies the former. @Stratossupportsthestrike

Now I see, I did miss that point indeed ! Thanks again for your help :)
